# Regarding a parameter of Geocode API

Tags: here-api

Regarding Geocode API [maxresults], do you have any limit of maximum number of responses for search results?
Regarding Places(Search) API, how do I set the limit of maximum number of responses? Do you have an parameter of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding Geocode API [maxresults], do you have any limit of maximum number of responses for search results?** 
There is no limit on the maximum responses for search results. But there is a limit on the result relevance (usually 100%, displayed in the response).

**Regarding Places(Search) API, how do I set the limit of maximum number of responses? Do you have an parameter of it?**

Yes, you can to use the size parameter for it. In the below example, we are restricting the number of results returned in the response to 2 by appending size=2 to the query.

```
https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/around?at=41.8369%2C-87.684&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&size=2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was practical!
I understood maximum number of responses about GeocodeAPI and Place API.